# Store the output of the Python matplotlib function of pcolormesh and reconstruct it

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, ifft

I am gonna apply [Short Time Fourier Transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) on this [signal](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pietr0NhWF3jHqTo0ZoxYSF1zaKKPPMM) and plot the results using [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) function. Then, I want to use [Inverse Short Time Fourier Transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.istft.html) to reconstruct the signal. My question is how to use the output of the pcolormesh as input for signal.istft(Zxx) to get the signal back. In short this is what I want to do:

```
f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(sig, fs=250, nperseg=64)
mesh=plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

which outputs this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS62E.png). Then, apply the inverse Fourier Transform to reconstruct the signal:

```
_, xrec = signal.istft(mesh, fs=250)
```

Actually, I am not sure if the mesh input for the above function is the right way to do or not? And how I can get the correct input for the signal.istft(Zxx) instead of Zxx?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. The returned array from `stft` is an array of complex numbers. When you plot the array, you take the magnitude `np.abs()` of the complex numbers to turn them into real numbers. But you need the full complex info to apply the inverse `istft`. Maybe you can explain why you cannot use `Zxx` directly?

Comment: Tnx @DizietAsahi for your comment. Actually, I am going to use these images as inputs for training a generative adversarial network and the output of the network will be images which I want to reconstruct the signal from them.